# Can you control/stream your PC to a laptop without lag?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, laptop, desktop-computer, wired-networking

hey I wish I could just sit in bed and use my high end pc without having to go to my desk . I already have a laptop so I was wondering if there is a way to control my pc using my laptop either through WIFI or wires without obvious lag .
if there is no way to control it without lag can I at least stream the screen without lag ?

Answer (score 0):

Technically, no it is not possible to control anything remotely without lag.  At the very minimum, taking no input from you (the client), the remote machine (the host) has to take what is being shown on the screen, convert it to usable data, and send it to the client.  Then the client has to read and display that data.  That takes time and time is lag.

You can reduce the time/lag, in many ways.  The obvious choice is faster connections.  The faster the connection, more data can be sent quicker.  Speaking of data, reducing the amount of data is often how many remote desktop programs work.  Reducing the resolution, reducing the amount of colors, reducing the number of frames it grabs, even looking for only sections of the screen that have changed.  There are other methods as well.

In the end, you can play with your settings and you might get a decent remote experience, but it is truly a function of everything.  There is no one thing that will make it work perfectly.  That, and you can break the laws of physics.

Comment: thank you for your reply i appreciate it much . what about using wires ? is there a way to control my pc by the laptop through wires without obvious lag

Comment: @MohamedShatarah  thats a meaningless question.  Wired can be faster than wireless.  wireless can be faster than wired.  It depends entirely on the network specifications.

Comment: Also note, that there are all kinds of lag, and situations where they are acceptable or not. for instance video streaming works well when the client can request that the server starts the stream, and then the client handles all the buffering, and the features instrumentation, but for remote control of a desktop, the server has to let you interrupt it with every click or move of the mouse, and the server needs to be responsive to those signals, but it also means that streaming video over this connection will lag, even though the desktop is quite responsive.